# Can a lens exist with an f-stop of less than 1?

Tags: f-stop

As I understand it, the F-number of a lens is equal to the aperture diameter divided by the focal length. So f/1 would mean that the aperture is as wide as the lens is long.

Question: Is it physically possible for the aperture to somehow be *wider* than that? For example, something like an f/0.5 lens?

I gather that F-number is already the number one cause of expensive lenses, so even if such a lens is physically possible, it's likely to be far to expensive to actually buy. (To say nothing about whether it's even *useful* in the first place.) I'm just curious about the physics of the matter.

Comment: Less interested in whether there's one for sale, more just "is it physically possible?" And apparently it is...

Comment: "So f/1 would mean that the aperture is as wide as the lens is long." The _focal length_ is not the same as the _length_ of a lens.

Comment: I had an f/0.85 C-mount lens in a previous job.  I tried it on my Canon 350D but of course I had no infinity focus and lost the corners to vignetting. But they exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there have been numerous lenses made that are faster then f/1.0

One of the most famous is the Zeiss_Planar_50mm_f/0.7 which was was designed for the NASA and used by Stanley Kubrick in *[Barry Lyndon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Lyndon#Cinematography)* to shoot several indoor scenes by candlelight.

[Zeiss_Planar_50mm_f/0.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Zeiss_Planar_50mm_f/0.7)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn you ;) 
... I was just about to post a f/.9 from Leica

Comment: I bet that was cheap then... :-}

Comment: The Zeiss lens of course is not cheap, but here, for example, is a not unaffordable f/0.95 lens for Sony E-Mount retailing for ~US$850: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1072733-REG/mitakon_mtk50mf095bk_50mm_for_0_95_lens.html

Comment: didn't Canon make a 50mm f/0.95 at one point in EF mount? or did I dream that.